# select_tag Ajax Updation with Rails3 + Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a select_tag which displays product category types. I want to do an Ajax update when a user selects a product category and list down all the products in a div below the select tag.

I think I'll be able to handle the product display part with a partial and js template. But i dont know how to implement the

product category selection
doing an ajax request (with parameters) to rails controller. (Almost all the examples in web is bind with ajax form updation....)

can someone help me out- thanks in advance

I'm using rails 3, Jquery

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you gave us more information about your data models. I'll sketch out what I think you have based on your question.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

and assuming you have your routes set up:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end
```

what you need to do is wireup the `change` event of the `select_tag` to request a list of products based on the category id that was selected.

```
$('select#categories').change(function(){
  var category_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $.getJSON(
    '/categories/' + category_id + '/products',
    function(response) {
      // render your template on the page here
    }
  );
});
```

I've written a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/lyconic/jquery.rest) to simplify basic RESTful interactions with a Rails controller, so it could be written as:

```
$('select#categories').change(function(){
  var category_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $.read(
    '/categories/{category_id}/products',
    { category_id: category_id },
    function (response) {
      // render your template
    }
  );
});
```

While `$.read` isn't much simpler than `$.getJSON`, the other operations will save you a lot of typing.

The rest of the implementation rests in the controller, but you have a lot more leeway in how to implement that, so I can't really guess what would be helpful to you without more information.

Comment: Hi Adam. thanks for the details explanation.. Sorry for not giving much details.. I'll tryout your code and update the status... thanks again... sameera

Comment: thanks adam, I finally got it up and running, thanks for the help

Comment: @sameera207, could you please share the code that finally worked for you? working on a similar task myself and found this post. thanks a lot!